# getting key and value in two separate arrays

Tags: dojo

Hi I need to get the month ans value in two separate arrays one for key month and one for key value separately, for below mention data

```
var data = [{month: "JUL", value:"5"},
            {month: "AUG", value:"7"},
            {month: "SEP", value:"9"},
            {month: "OCT", value:"11"},
            {month: "NOV", value:"13"},    
            {month: "DEC", value:"15"},
            {month: "JAN", value:"17"},
            {month: "FEB", value:"19"},
            {month: "MAR", value:"21"},
            {month: "APR", value:"23"},
            {month: "MAY", value:"25"},
            {month: "JUN", value:"27"}];
```

I am trying to do in the below mentioned way

```
var output = [];
for(var key in response)
    for(var value in response[key])
      {
    output.push(response[key][value]);
     }
    alert("output ---------------------->"+output);
```

Kindly help ...

Comment: Don't forget "hasOwnProperty" when you use "for ... in" in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial question says you want to get the values into two separate arrays, then in your code you've only declared one 'output' array so I'm not entirely sure what you really want to do, but maybe something like this:

```
var months = [];
var values = [];

for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
    months.push(data[i]["month"]);
    values.push(data[i]["value"]);
}
```

Your initial declaration of 'data' was as an array of objects, where each object has two properties. You don't want to use the for(x in y) syntax for an array; use a traditional for() like in my example.

Comment: On server side i am fetching value from database and creating a JSONArray as mentined below JSON Array :[{"value":"5","month":"JUL"},{"value":"7","month":"AUG"},{"value":"9","month":"SEP"},{"value":"11","month":"OCT"},{"value":"13","month":"NOV"},{"value":"15","month":"DEC"},{"value":"17","month":"JAN"},{"value":"19","month":"FEB"},{"value":"21","month":"MAR"},{"value":"23","month":"APR"},{"value":"25","month":"MAY"},{"value":"27","month":"JUN"}]

Comment: And on jsp i am doing something like this to get key and value :

Comment: dojo.xhrGet( {
url : "/ApprovalPortalPOC/ApprovalPortalAction.do",
handleAs : "json",
sync: true,
//Retriving the json values from response.
for(var key in response)
  for(var value in response[key])
  {
     output.push(response[key][value]);
     }
             alert("output ---------------------->"+output);
       return response;
      },
        error: function(response, ioArgs){
         dojo.byId("grid").innerHTML = "An error occurred, with response: " + response;
         return response;
         },
         handleAs: "json"
       });